# How to handle Phoenix redirect and react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, elixir, phoenix-framework

I use Phoenix for server side rendering. When confirm Phoenix redirect to    /authentication#/ConfirmSuccess like this code

```
defp is_confirm_code_success(conn, {:ok, res}) do
 redirect conn, to: "/authentication#/ConfirmSuccess"
end
```

But in react I can't Route to /authentication#/ConfirmSuccess.

```
<Route exact path="/authentication#/ConfirmUnSuccess" component={ConfirmSuccess} />
```

it always point to /authentication.